# Add filters to scatter plot based on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, scatter-plot

I am pretending to do a scatter plots with filters of the following dataframe (that represents in a whole season the players, the team and the season, and counts the asissted and not assisted point that a player of a basketball team did):

```
player          team_name       season          assisted    notassisted
A. DANRIDGE     NACIONAL        Season_17_18    130         445
A. DANRIDGE     NACIONAL        Season_18_19    132         382
D. ROBINSON     TROUVILLE       Season_18_19    89          286
D. DAVIS        AGUADA          Season_18_19    101         281
E. BATISTA      WELCOME         Season_17_18    148         278
F. MARTINEZ     GOES            Season_18_19    52          259
D. ALVAREZ      AGUADA          Season_17_18    114         246
M. HICKS        H. MACABI       Season_17_18    140         245
```

In the x axis I want to put the assisted points and in the y axis the not assisted points. But I also want to filter by season, by team and by players, so when I select a determined player of a team I can see their points with one color and the other points greyed, or for example if I want to select two or more players I can compare them between them (with different colors) and that the other points are visible but greyed. Also I would like to compare the players of two different teams and combinations of the filters.

I am learning data science and with the library plotly express I can make the scatter plot and filter by team for example, and I can compare two different teams (or seasons or players).

But I am not able to add multiple filters in a fancy way, and also I don't know how to show the selected and put in grey the others (without disapearing them).

The code is the following:

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.scatter(pointsperplayer, x='assisted', y='notassisted', hover_name='player', 
                 hover_data=['team_name','season'], color='season')
fig.show()
```

And the graph resultant is the following:

[Scatter plot resultant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxIS9.jpg)

In summary, I would like to have three filters, one for season, other for team, the other for players, to be able to have multiple selections in each filter, and to obtain different colors and the rest of the points greyed so I can compare the results with the rests, I am not sure if it is possible with plotly express or if I should use a different library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was not able to manipulate the legend, but I could add filters through drop down widgets that I found [here](https://plot.ly/python/figurewidget-app/). Depending on your IDE, you might need to use Jupyter to get the widgets to work. I ran into the problem of VSCode not being able to display widgets. What I have below is the ability to filter by team name, season, or player and compare two options within that filter. I hope this can be expanded to meet your needs.

```python
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import ipywidgets as ipy
from ipywidgets import Output, VBox, widgets


# First gather the data I need and choose the display colors
playerData = pd.read_csv("playerData.csv")
teamNames = list(playerData['team_name'].unique().tolist());
seasons = list(playerData['season'].unique().tolist());
players = list(playerData['player'].unique().tolist());
color1 = 'red'
color2 = 'blue'
color3 = 'gray'

# This creates the initial figure.
# Note that px.scatter generates multiple scatter plot 'traces'. Each trace contains 
# the data points associated with 1 team/season/player depending on what the property
# of 'color' is set to.
trace1 = px.scatter(playerData, x='assisted', y='notassisted', color='team_name')
fig = go.FigureWidget(trace1)

# Create all our drop down widgets
filterDrop = widgets.Dropdown(
    description='Filter:',
    value='team_name',
    options=['team_name', 'season','player']  
)
teamDrop1 = widgets.Dropdown(
    description='Team Name:',
    value='NACIONAL',
    options=list(playerData['team_name'].unique().tolist())  
)
teamDrop2 = widgets.Dropdown(
    description='Team Name:',
    value='NACIONAL',
    options=list(playerData['team_name'].unique().tolist())  
)
playerDrop1 = widgets.Dropdown(
    description='Player:',
    value='A. DANRIDGE',
    options=list(playerData['player'].unique().tolist())  
)
playerDrop2 = widgets.Dropdown(
    description='Player:',
    value='A. DANRIDGE',
    options=list(playerData['player'].unique().tolist())  
)
seasonDrop1 = widgets.Dropdown(
    description='Season:',
    value='Season_17_18',
    options=list(playerData['season'].unique().tolist())  
)
seasonDrop2 = widgets.Dropdown(
    description='Season:',
    value='Season_17_18',
    options=list(playerData['season'].unique().tolist())  
)

# This will be called when the filter dropdown changes. 
def filterResponse(change):
    # generate the new traces that are filtered by teamname, season, or player
    tempTrace = px.scatter(playerData, x='assisted', y='notassisted', color=filterDrop.value)
    with fig.batch_update():
        # Delete the old traces and add the new traces in one at a time
        fig.data = []
        for tr in tempTrace.data:
            fig.add_scatter(x = tr.x, y = tr.y, hoverlabel = tr.hoverlabel, hovertemplate = tr.hovertemplate, \
                           legendgroup = tr.legendgroup, marker = tr.marker, mode = tr.mode, name = tr.name)
    # Call response so that it will color the markers appropriately
    response(change)

# This is called by all the other drop downs
def response(change):
    # colorList is a list of strings the length of the # of traces 
    if filterDrop.value == 'team_name':
        colorList = [color1 if x == teamDrop1.value else color2 if x == teamDrop2.value else color3 for x in teamNames]
    elif filterDrop.value == 'season':
        colorList = [color1 if x == seasonDrop1.value else color2 if x == seasonDrop2.value else color3 for x in seasons]
    else:
        colorList = [color1 if x == playerDrop1.value else color2 if x == playerDrop2.value else color3 for x in players]
    with fig.batch_update():
        # Color each trace according to our chosen comparison traces
        for i in range(len(colorList)):
            fig.data[i].marker.color = colorList[i]

# These determine what function should be called when a drop down changes
teamDrop1.observe(response, names="value")
seasonDrop1.observe(response, names="value")
playerDrop1.observe(response, names="value")
teamDrop2.observe(response, names="value")
seasonDrop2.observe(response, names="value")
playerDrop2.observe(response, names="value")
filterDrop.observe(filterResponse, names="value")

# HBox and VBox are used to organize the other widgets and figures
container1 = widgets.HBox([filterDrop]) 
container2 = widgets.HBox([teamDrop1, seasonDrop1, playerDrop1])
container3 = widgets.HBox([teamDrop2, seasonDrop2, playerDrop2])
widgets.VBox([container1, container2, container3, fig])
```

The result looks like this:[image]